# add a parameter with js function window.history.back()

Tags: javascript, function, url, input, parameters

I've this button:

```
<input id="backbutton" type="button" value="Back" onClick="javascript:window.history.back()"/>
```

how I could add url parameters to return in back page, like "index=1", with this javascript function?

Comment: `javascript:window.history.back(-5)` goes back 5 pages. Is that what you mean?

Comment: what if i wanted to do this with the native browser back button, and not a button element I've created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this :

```
document.getElementById('backbutton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.location = document.referrer + '?index=1';
}, false);
```

Comment: This is not the same as history.back() for it will lose for example all filled in form data, but if you just want to jump back to a page without Get/Post Vars its fine.

Comment: it works, but how can I go back two pages without lose a filled form?

Comment: append query parameters to your URL and restore them, if they are present, on your form page

Answer (score 2):

You can  use cookies :

```
<input id="backbutton" type="button" value="Back" onClick="runMe()"/>

function runMe()
{
 document.cookie = name+"=index%3d1; expires=whenever;path=/";
 window.history.back()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `window.history` you can modify the user's current history with [`window.history.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history?#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method), but note that this method is only available in modern browsers:

- Chrome 5+
- Firefox 4+
- IE 10+
- Opera 11.5+
- Safari 5+

For a more backwards compatible solution, you should avoid `window.history` altogether and instead use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location), setting an explicit URL instead of relying on the user's history.